# How to save opened file in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I open file as:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

     //
    }
```

How can I save immediately this file in disc? I tried:

```
File.Copy(openFileDialog.FileName, @"C:\");
```

Comment: The second parameter to file copy needs to be the full path AND filename, not just the folder you want to copy it to - see this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx - you also need write permission to the folder you are saving to

Comment: Try `File.Copy(openFileDialog.FileName, Path.Combine("C:\\", Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `File.Copy()` the absolute path, including the name of the file it's saving.
`"C:\"` is not a valid file name, so it can't save it.
Try something like:

```
string fName = "myPhoto";
File.Copy(openFileDialog.FileName, @"C:\" + fName + ".jpg");
```

Source:
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx)

[PaulF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3070060/paulf) also mentioned this in the comments prior to my posting this answer.